# groupbyでカンマ区切りのデータを一つずつ要素として取り出し、配列に格納したい

Tags: python, pandas

**- 環境**
macOS Mojave
Python 3.7.3
Jupyter Notebook 6.0.0

**- やりたいこと**
以下のように、[data]の各行に単一またはカンマ区切りで複数のデータがあります。
[No]をキーとしたgroupbyで、[data]のデータを一つずつ取り出して配列を作りたいです。

[image]

**-- 期待するアウトプット（list型でもSeries型でも構いません）**

```py
No
1    [a, a, b, 1, 2, 3]
2        [a, aa, bb, 1]
```

**- やったこと**
以下のコードを実行しましたが、カンマ区切りの複数データを分割して単一の要素として配列に格納することができません。

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/USER/Desktop/dataframe.xlsx')
df = df.astype({'data': 'str'})

def singlelabel_generator(group):
    group_ = group['data'].values
    elements_list = [el.strip(', ') for el in group_]

    return elements_list

elements_list = df.groupby('No').apply(singlelabel_generator)

for el_check in elements_list:
    print(el_check)

# 出力結果
# ['a', 'a,b', '1', '2', '3'] <-'a,b'が'a', 'b'に分割されていない
# ['a', 'aa,bb', '1'] <-'aa,bb'が'aa', 'bb'に分割されていない
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使う関数が`strip()`ではなく`split()`にすべきなのと、多くても2次元のリストでしょうから、`sum()`で1次元化出来るでしょう。次元が増えるのなら紹介記事の他のやり方を試してみてください。

[文字列の削除 split(), strip(), replace(), translate(), re.sub()](http://python-remrin.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/04/24/174405)

> split()
> 　区切り文字(delimiter)を区切りとして、文字列を分割しリストを返す。
>
> strip()
> 　文字列の両端から指定文字をはぎとる。

[Pythonでflatten（多次元リストを一次元に平坦化）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-flatten/)

> sum()
> 組み込み関数のsum()を使う方法もある。
> sum()の第二引数には初期値を指定できる。ここに空のリスト[]を指定すると、リストの+演算によって、要素のリストが連結される。

また、`def singlelabel_generator(group):`で`label_list`を処理している部分は何処にも影響を及ぼしていないので、冗長な処理です。

ちなみに、期待するアウトプットの2行目は、`[a, aa, ,bb, 1]`ではなく`[a, aa, bb, 1]`(bbの前の`,`が余分)では？

macOS, Jupyter Notebookの環境でどうなるかはわかりませんが、
まとめると、`def singlelabel_generator(group):`は以下のようになるのでは？

```
def singlelabel_generator(group):
    group_ = group['data'].values
    elements_list = sum([el.split(',') for el in group_], [])
    
    return elements_list
```

Windows10で素のPythonではこうなりました。

```
['a', 'a', 'b', '1', '2', '3']
['a', 'aa', 'bb', '1']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。お教えいただいたsum()の処置で対応いたしました。
また、ご指摘通りlabel_listは冗長であったため、削除いたしました。（デバッグ作業の消し忘れでした。）
期待するアウトプットの2行目もご指摘の通りです。

Comment: strip(', ')としたのは、カンマ区切りされたデータがスペースを含まないとは言い切れず、スペースも除去したかったためです。
最終的には以下のコードといたしました。
```python
def singlelabel_generator(group):
    group_ = group['data'].values
    elements_list = sum([el.replace(', ', ',').split(',') for el in group_], [])
    return elements_list
```